# Fade to black in HMD Oculus Quest 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusquest

I am currently trying to fade the screen to black when the player exceed a specified y-value (when they stand up). I am using Unity for Oculus Quest 2 (And I'm a newbie).

I have tried just using a Canvas (Image), but I have trouble making it become the "foremost" overlay. How would you approach this? It would also be very nice with a fade to black effect (maybe as coroutine?)

Thank you!

I tried experimenting with the different Canvas rending modes, as I've seen people advising to use the World Space. I tried spawning in a black cube, but obviously when I'm inside the cube it does not go full black.

Comment: The problem about Screenspace overlay Canvas is that afaik it won't be rendered in XR devices as it would basically sit directly in your face ^^ I would probably rather go for Post-Processing and e.g. fade the entire rendering to black in [`OnRenderImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage.html)

Comment: I am unsure if post processing is viable on platforms like the Oculus Quest?

Comment: I'd simply try ;)

Answer (score 1):

Put a cube right at near-clipping-plane distance of the camera. The cube should be big enough to cover the whole FOV. Fade the cube's color via the material. Done:)

Note: Using a cube avoids the problem that in MR applications non-world-space UI elements do not work as intended!